# Is it possible to move SymbolLayer icon as per the updated location points?

Tags: mapbox-android

I wants to move SymbolLayer icon on the map layer as per the position change, move like as a marker. In the latest Mapbox update, MarkerView and MarkerViewOptions is deprecated. So I want to move the SymbolLayer icon.

Please help me to make it work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this and it's kinda' dependent on what type of source + layer you're going to use. First read https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/overview/geojson/#geojson-updates

1. https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/animate-marker-position/
2. If you're using a `GeoJsonSource`, you'll set new geojson on the source when you know the new coordinate(s) that you want the `SymbolLayer` icon to move to https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/search?q=setGeoJson. Make sure you're updating the `GeoJsonSource` that the `SymbolLayer` is using.
3. There's the annotation plugin, which handles lots of the layer/source boilerplate code you'd have to ordinarily write: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/annotation/. `symbol.setLatLng();` and `symbolManager.update();` will be helpful. See https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/testapp/activity/annotation/SymbolActivity.java and https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/examples/symbol-listener/